# Pickle: Reading a dictionary, EOFError

Tags: python, pickle, maya, eoferror

I recently found out about pickle, which is amazing. But it errors on me when used for my actual script, testing it with a one item dictionary it worked fine. My real script is thousands of lines of code storing various objects within maya into it. I do not know if it has anything to do with the size, I have read around a lot of threads here but none are specific to my error.

I have tried writing with all priorities. No luck.

This is my output code:

```
    output = open('locatorsDump.pkl', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(l.locators, output, -1)
    output.close()
```

This is my read code:

```
    jntdump = open('locatorsDump.pkl', 'rb')
    test = pickle.load(jntdump)
    jntdump.close()
```

This is the error:

```
    # Error: Error in  maya.utils._guiExceptHook:
    #   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2011\Python\lib\site-packages\pymel-1.0.0-py2.6.egg\maya\utils.py", line 277, in formatGuiException
    #     exceptionMsg = excLines[-1].split(':',1)[1].strip()
    # IndexError: list index out of range
    # 
    # Original exception was:
    # Traceback (most recent call last):
    #   File "<maya console>", line 3, in <module>
    #   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2011\bin\python26.zip\pickle.py", line 1370, in load
    #     return Unpickler(file).load()
    #   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2011\bin\python26.zip\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    #     dispatch[key](self)
    #   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2011\bin\python26.zip\pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    #     raise EOFError
    # EOFError #
```

Comment: Try to work out what's the smallest thing that causes this error when you pickle/unpickle it. Without knowing what you've done, there's not a lot anyone else can do about it.

Answer (score 4):

Try using pickle.dumps() and pickle.loads() as a test.
If you don't recieve the same error, you know it is related to the file write.